# Swift multiple callback handlers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for iOS to delete a user. For this I need to reauthenticate the user first and then delete the account.

I pass the completion handler from `.delete()` to my view and then I check for errors. But what if there is an error during `.reauthenticate()`

How can I pass both `UserProfileChangeCallback` and `AuthDataResultCallback` handlers back to my view? I need to get errors and result from both of them.

```
func delete(password: String, handler: @escaping UserProfileChangeCallback) -> Void {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

        // user.reauthenticate(with: AuthCredential, completion: AuthDataResultCallback?)

        user.reauthenticate(with: EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: user.email!, password: password)) { (result, error) in //AuthDataResult?
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // I need this error in my view too
            } else {
                user.delete(completion: handler)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can I pass both UserProfileChangeCallback and AuthDataResultCallback handlers back to my view?" You can't, and you shouldn't need to. Just call `handler` from the point of your comment and tell it whatever it needs to know.

Comment: What you need to do is define your own callback with a custom set of errors. Don't expose `UserProfileChangeCallback` or `AuthDataResultCallback` to your view.

Comment: got it. Any idea how to NOT nest them inside the other?